# react-native-setTimeout do not work well

Tags: react-native, settimeout

I want to change the state by setTimeout

componentDidMount() {

```
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            splashed: true
        })
        console.log('!');
    }, 5000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('nani');
    this.timer && clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```

but the setTimeout run soon when trigger componentDidMount , do not wait 5 seconds.  how can i do it?
Thanks for your any suggestions.

Comment: maybe you should show more codeline, cuz this snippet does work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another function for setting the state:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setSplashed();
        console.log('!');
    }, 5000)
}

setSplashed = () => {
    this.setState({
        splashed: true
    })
}
```